# How to make horizontal scrollbar and a div below an HTML table sticked to the bottom of the table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

**[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8w7f4vhd/4/)**

I have an HTML table with number of columns greater than what can be displayed without scrolling. So there is horizontal scrolling enabled.

Moreover, there is vertical scrolling also enabled on the table at all times.

I want two things:

1. At present, the horizontal scrollbar comes into view (i.e. the viewport) only when the vertical scrollbar is used to scroll DOWN the table contents to a certain extent. What I want is that the horizontal scrollbar is visible (i.e. in the viewport) at all times, even when the table is vertically NOT scrolled at all.
2. There is a small `<div>` below the `<table>`. I need it to overlay the table, such that it is sticked to the bottom of the `.container` `<div>` at all times.

How can I achieve this?

---

***@Yasir*** I can't see the horizontal scrollbar. I need it to be visible at all time, just like the yellow colored `div` is visible (fixed to the bottom) at all times.

[image]

Comment: Now why a downvote?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  You probably also got a big red warning about links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself.  If you ignore the rules, then expect downvotes

Comment: Wow! Downvotes attract more downvotes

Comment: @Pete I Have included a small example JSFiddle linked in the start of the question. The specific problems are given as two numbered points.

Comment: Read my comment and the bit highlighted in bold , anyway if you ignore the rules and can't be bothered, then I can't be bothered to spend time making an answer

Comment: @Sie _"Wow! Downvotes attract more downvotes"_ -  they do indeed. That's why it's very important to read and follow the rules and put maximum effort in to your questions.

Comment: @Pete About the bit in bold, there are 3000 characters allowed in SO questions, and mine were more than 6000. The code has a huge HTML table. I think even getting rid of some rows (although I need many rows to show that I need scrolling on the wwebpage) would get me rid of THREE THOUSAND characters.

Comment: Please read this and make one accordingly: [mcve] - i.e. you don't need to include all your code or even the whole table, just make enough to show your error, by doing this it sometimes helps you to see what has gone wrong

Comment: @Pete Thank you. I'll follow the guide.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
table {
  margin-bottom:60px;
}

.table-container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin-bottom:66px;

}

.div-for-pagination {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
```

fiddler:
https://jsfiddle.net/8w7f4vhd/30/

Comment: Please see the screenshot I have added in the question.  I can't see the horizontal scrollbar. I need it to be visible at all time, just like the yellow colored div is visible (fixed to the bottom) at all times.

Comment: Hi, firstly thank you for your help. Just upvoted your answer and I will also mark it as the best answer. But can you kindly help me a little more? What if the page also has a header and footer? Header renders correctly, but the footer renders right next to the header, overlaying the table. [**JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/8w7f4vhd/36/)

Comment: Do you want the footer to be visible always or get it on scroll?

Comment: Get it on scroll

Comment: For the you will need to look as stick divs: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin
[Plugin](https://github.com/Amphiluke/floating-scroll)

You can use it like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".yourClassName").floatingScroll();
});
```

So your horizontal scrollbar will have fixed position